# Как правильно прокинуть props в дочетний компонент

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

У меня есть `Store`, `App` и компонент, который генерирует `PDF-документ` на основании данных, которые я вытаскиваю из `API` сервиса

Проблема появляется, когда данные поступают в компонент, вылетает ошибка:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

**Store.js**

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx'

class Store {

  @observable dd //Вот он, не теряем его

  constructor() {
    this.dd = {
      content: [
        {
          text: 'Topvisor',
          style: 'header'
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  @action('get Topvisor data')
  getTopvisorData() {
    fetch("https://api.topvisor.ru/v2/json/get/positions_2/history", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {...},
      body: JSON.stringify({...})
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
     })
    .then(data => {
      this.dd.content.push({ul: data.result.keywords.name}) //Тут добавили данные
      console.log(this.dd);
    });
  }
}

export default Store
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PDFGenerate from './components/PDFGenerate/PDFGenerate';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import Store from './store'

@observer
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = new Store
    this.state.getTopvisorData()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PDFGenerate data = {this.state.dd}/> //Тут передали данные
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**PDFGenerate.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

@observer
class PDFGenerate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.props.data // Тут их получили
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="PDFGenerate">
        <button onClick={this.generatePDF} type="button">Давай сюда отчет</button> // Тут вызвали
      </div>
    );
  }
  generatePDF() {
    pdfMake.createPdf(this.state).open() // А тут ошибка
  }
}

export default PDFGenerate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дополню первый ответ @mufdvr по комментарию  "Тогда вылетает ошибка Unrecognized document structure: {}". Дело в том, что в вашей структуре content - это массив. Но, когда вы делаете объект observable, то массив преобразовывается в объект, который уже не является классическим массивом:

**P.S**

Нашел один момент - это особенность pdfMake - внутри createPdf должен лежать объект со свойством content

> Due to limitations of native arrays in ES5 observable.array will create a faux-array (array-like object) instead of a real array. https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html

И если pdfMake не умеет работать с таким объектом (не работал с ним, не могу сказать точно), то будет ошибка. Передавать напрямую observable объект ему нельзя.

Как выход, можно создать "геттер" в вашем Store, который будет возвращать "классический" массив:

```
@computed get contentArray() {
    return this.dd.content.slice();
}
```

и вызывать:

```
<PDFGenerate data = {this.state}/>
```

а в компоненте

```
pdfMake.createPdf({content: this.props.data.contentArray}).open()
```

Comment: через геттер передается массив из `Proxy` и внутри отгенеренного `pdf` получается пусто. Это из-за того, что передается `Proxy` или как?

Comment: точно не могу сказать. не работал с pdfMake. Лучше всего включить отладчик в браузере и смотреть по шагам, что приходит на каком этапе

Comment: ну дело в том, что если поместить объект внутрь компонента, статический текст будет нормально отображен

Comment: Нашел один момент - это особенность pdfMake - внутри createPdf должен лежать объект со свойством `content`

Answer (score 3):

Функция generatePDF() не знает что такое this. 
Используйте либо "стрелочные" функции:

```
generatePDF = () => {
  pdfMake.createPdf(this.state).open()
}
```

либо выполните привязку контекста в конструкторе:

```
this.generatePDF = this.generatePDF.bind(this)
```

также вернее будет не this.state = this.props.data, а this.state = props.data

Comment: Тогда вылетает ошибка `Unrecognized document structure: {}`

Comment: Вы проверяли что передаете в функцию? похоже что там пустой объект